# Checkbox prompt in Report Builder 3.0

Tags: checkbox, prompt, reportbuilder3.0

I want to set up several prompts as a checkboxes in Report Builder 3.0.  Is this possible?  I've set up prompts for drop down lists, textboxes, date paramters, etc.  But I've never set one up as a checkbox.  Is this possible? How is it done?  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easy.

1. Right Click "Parameters"
2. Click "Add Parameter"
3. Set "Boolean" as the Data Type
4. Fill in the other fields as appropriate

And that's it.

Comment: @Dan_Scally...............Can they be made interactive?  Like if one is true the other ones are changed to false?  These are being used to filter the results.

Comment: You can't have a circular dependancy as far as I know; as in you couldn't set any of them to True and then have all the others turn False. You could have one particular one trigger the others though. Like setting Parameter A would change Parameters B, C and D to False, but manually changing B, C or D could not then alter A.

Comment: @Dan_Scally...........Thanks.  The user was thinking of checkboxes in Excel where you could turn one on and the others off.  They may have to settle for a drop down with only 1 selection.  Thanks for taking the time to respond.